# Change color of some keywords in inputbox

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am developing an editor for Cucumber feature file, when writing step definitions i want to use blue text color for Given, When , Then etc, and for the text between < > i want to use red color.

Is there a way, where we can change the color of text in the input field?

my code sample is like below.

```html
<form ng-submit="submit(senario)">
  <input type="text" placeholder="step definiton" ng-model="senario.step"
                   required="required" />
</form>
```

Comment: Not with just CSS. Google something like "js syntax highlighting".

Comment: do you mean to change the input field color or the placeholder colour?

Comment: i meant to change the color of a specific word in the input box

Answer (score 0):

You cannot highlights words only inside of an input. You should use a more advanced editor.

The best I could suggest you is CodeMirror, it already is capable to highligh a fair number of languages and got a plugin to ease the creation of your own (SimpleMode).

You could also do one yourself if you want... CodeMirror might be heavy for just 3 keywords... But you'll need to work hard. You will need to use an element with `contentEditable` and listen on some event (sorry can't remember which one exactly) to know the content changed and split text nodes and surround your keywords in spans.